# Remove lines, based on date comparison

Tags: python, pandas

I am having a dataframe that contains the following data:

```
Estimate     Value       Announce date      Period       Company
Estimate 1:  0,24        01-01-2015         31-12-2015     X
Estimate 2:  0,22        08-04-2015         31-12-2015     X
Estimate 3   0,26        07-05-2015         31-12-2014     Y
Estimate 4:  0,29        21-09-2015         31-12-2014     Y
Estimate 5:  0,21        30-09-2015         31-12-2013     Z
```

I would like to include only the **earliest** estimate **per period** and per **company**.

Example: Company x has for the period 31-12-2015 two estimates, 1 and 2, but estimate 1 has an earlier announce date than estimate 2. So I would like to delete the row for estimate 2, and then this for every period and company.

Announce date, and period are both in `datetime` format.

What is a proper method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: my first guess would be to create a dictionary keyed on period and then have a set for the announce dates and sort it based on that and only take the first element

Comment: Can you give me an example  of that ?

Comment: or an easier way to do it if the periods are grouped is to just set the first one as the earliest date, check the next one, if earlier than delete set earliest to that one and delete the previous, else delete the new one.

Comment: @SirParselot thanks for your reply, I was checking if your idea of grouping the periods could work, however, I forget to mention that the company must also be unique. Since there are companies that have the same periods.

Comment: You could make a tuple that is (period, company) but that seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC then you can just call [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first) on the groupby object:

```
In [191]:
df.groupby(['Period','Company']).first()

Out[191]:
                      Estimate Value AnnounceDate
Period     Company                               
2013-12-31 Z        Estimate5:  0,21   2015-09-30
2014-12-31 Y        Estimate3:  0,26   2015-07-05
2015-12-31 X        Estimate1:  0,24   2015-01-01
```

If you want to sorted results then sort the df prior to the `groupby`:

```
In [194]:
df.sort(columns='AnnounceDate').groupby(['Period','Company']).first()

Out[194]:
                      Estimate Value AnnounceDate
Period     Company                               
2013-12-31 Z        Estimate5:  0,21   2015-09-30
2014-12-31 Y        Estimate3:  0,26   2015-07-05
2015-12-31 X        Estimate1:  0,24   2015-01-01
```

Comment: This is actually nicer if you call sort first for safety

Comment: I wasn't sure if the OP wanted first by date or estimate

Comment: Thanks! And how can I specify that it must sort on Announcedate, if I have more columns in my dataframe? (To learn something extra from this question ;)

Comment: I'd sort first before the groupby, so `df.sort('Announcedate')` will udpate

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to group the data by period then rank, followed by a subset of Rank = 1:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

s = u"""Estimate Value AnnounceDate Period Company
Estimate1: 0,24 01-01-2015 31-12-2015 X
Estimate2: 0,22 08-04-2015 31-12-2015 X
Estimate3: 0,26 07-05-2015 31-12-2014 Y
Estimate4: 0,29 21-09-2015 31-12-2014 Y
Estimate5: 0,21 30-09-2015 31-12-2013 Z"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), delimiter=" ")
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['Period','Company'])['AnnounceDate'].rank(ascending=True)
df[df['Rank']==1]
```

Comment: thanks for your example, but how do I include the companies in this? See my editted post.

Comment: You can pass multiple fields to the groupby method (edited)